# relay WebHttpRelayBinding to webapi service

Tags: azure, servicebus, asp.net-web-api

I have a desktop webapi server that I want to expose to clients through azure service bus's relay WebHttpRelayBinding  is there a simple way to capture all the messages from the service bus and pass them as http requests to my webapi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pedro Félix has implemented a host that implements just what you are looking for.

He describes it in a [blog post](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/asp-net-web-api-creating-an-host-using-azure-service-bus/), and has [put the code on GitHub](https://github.com/pmhsfelix/WebApi.Explorations.ServiceBusRelayHost).

Comment: I've tested Pedro's approach and can confirm that it works, its pretty neat! This will be handy for running some services on a home server that can be accessed from the outside world without punching ports open in my firewall.

Comment: While this is several years old, it'd be great if you included the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.